# Strange probs with popd and pushd

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

Just when I thought I got popd and pushd, when I tried to practice on my own...it all went to hell.

I removed the temp directory.I verified this by going through Finder.

Then I made a new set of nested directories. Suddenly, temp was back, and from what I'm looking at, I pushd ~ twice???

```
pats-MacBook-Pro:~ pat$ mkdir -p hello/"I AM"/so/confused
pats-MacBook-Pro:~ pat$ pushd hello/"I AM"/so/confused
~/hello/I AM/so/confused ~ ~/temp
pats-MacBook-Pro:confused pat$ dirs -v
 0  ~/hello/I AM/so/confused
 1  ~
 2  ~/temp
```

What on earth...?!?! What have I done wrong?

Thanks so much for your patience, all.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` just remember where you were. They are not related to the existence of directories.

Comment: That doesn't explain why ~ shows up on its own, or why temp suddenly reappeared :-\

Comment: Are you sure the directory stack was empty before you pushed `confused` to it?

Comment: Yes. I used rmdir to remove temp before I started.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir` and `rmdir` create and remove directories. `pushd` and `popd` are just an interface to a stack of locations. You can store a location in the stack, or retrieve it. The stack doesn't care whether the location stored in it  really exists.

In other words,  if you store a directory by `pushd` and remove it, it stays in the stack.  Calling `popd` would cause an error and the stack wouldn't change.